Variable DC-DC Buck Converter not working
I am building a variable power supply based on https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-050012

There are three GPIO signals that go to the MOSFET. The USB controller toggles one of the three GPIO signals to activate one of Q2, Q3, Q4 at a time. My understanding is that the MOSFET activates a path which changes the voltage divider on FB and allows the buck IC to target a new output voltage. If none of the GPIOs are active, the default output is 5V which is achieved by the voltage divider R4 and R10.
When selecting 9 V, 15 V, or 20 V, I see that R14, R15, or R16 will be in parallel which creates the new voltage divider value. The table on the bottom gives the desired output voltage and the equivalent resistance.
My design is slightly different in that my resistors are in series instead of parallel:

Here, for 5 V, I have a divider with R4 and R10-R13 and for the other voltages, I use the MOSFET to short the series resistors to get lower resistance values.
The problem is, without driving any GPIOs (Q5-Q7 are all off), I measure an output voltage of 11.88 V instead of 5 V.
P.S: What's more bizarre is if I use my multimeter and measure the resistance between the two pads on R13, I get ~7.2 kΩ instead of 8.2 kΩ. If I remove the inductor L1, then I measure 8.2 kΩ as expected. Maybe this is a quirk of my ohmmeter or something and is unrelated.

"What's more bizarre is if I use my multimeter and measure the resistance between the two pads on R13, I get ~7.2 kΩ instead of 8.2 kΩ" Stupid question but you turned the power off during the measurement, yeah?

@Lundin yes, the board was completely disconnected

These MOSFETs are all upside down and won't do what you expect them to do: -


The problem is, without driving any GPIOs (Q5-Q7 are all off), I
measure an output voltage of 11.88V instead of 5V.

Yes, this sounds likely to happen with the MOSFETs connected incorrectly. Look at the internal bulk diode directions to see why.

They also managed to displace the pull-down resistors on the gates vs the original design, so depending on what sits on the other side, the gate could be floating.

@Lundin yes the original design has a different use of those MOSFETs but, without seeing the driver for it, it's tricky to say. Personally I prefer source grounded but, the dynamics of the feedback signal is probably better with the resistor in the source.

@Lundin the controller has built in pull-downs do I didn't add any more

@Andyaka doh! thank you for catching this dumb mistake. I manually soldered the MOSFETs in a reversed orientation and used some wires to hook up pin 1 and everything now works as expected!
